# Uninstall application when testing

Tags: android, functional-testing, robotium

I'm new to testing in Android with Robotium. How can I programatically uninstall and then install the application before running some of the tests?

For example, in order for me to test the login activity, I need to make sure the login credentials are not saved from a prior run of the app. Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: adb install / uninstall could be a simple solution by using script… Did you consider that?

Comment: Yes. But I need to do the uninstall from inside my Java tests.

Comment: Arff… I don't know Robotium… Sorry and good luck…

Comment: On trying the answer, I got a "IOException: Permission denied" error. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following piece of code (on the machine you're debugging from) to uninstall your application:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("adb uninstall your.package");
pr.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

-You can also do that by using [UIAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#)
-Install the application from play store when starting your test and uninstall after finishing the test.
-Additionally It will always install new version from play store.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work though for real testing, as you normally test app versions that are NOT yet distributed in the app store, because you changed something locally and want to run tests on the new version to make sure you can actually distribute it.