# How can I automatically uninstall the app from the emulator after running the Android unit test

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, robotium

I am using Eclipse ADT to test an Android App.  However, after I execute the test suite once, the emulator will have the app installed.  I need to remove it from the emulator since the test will fail next time if the app is already installed on the emulator (due to some stored data).

I tried to search a way to start a clean emulator every time I run the test suite, but has no luck so far.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

BTW, I am using Robotium package.

Comment: I found this [Uninstall application when testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389465/uninstall-application-when-testing).  However, when I put the code inside the tearDown() method of my test class, the test always fails due to a process crash.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
adb -e uninstall your.test.package.name
```

Cleaner solution:

Back up a known good [`userdata-qemu.img`](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#diskimages) emulator disk image and restore it before launching the emulator for new test run.

Comment: where should I put the adb command? I am trying to do this process within the test suite.

Comment: This is external to the emulator, in a host OS shell session. Similarly, you can only access the disk images from the host OS side.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way. But there's an easy way to uninstall it:

- Go to the menu, where you see the app
- Hit the menu button, click "Manage Apps"
- Click your app
- It will ask you if you really want to uninstall it
- Click "Yes" or "Uninstall" button. It will be uninstalled with all the data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a SQLite database you can change the database version to a higher version than the actual version.

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; //in the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

This will call the onUpgrade function, there you can delete the tables and create them again.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //erase table
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MY_TABLE); 
    //create again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

If you're not using SQLite just overwrite the files.

Answer (score 0):

If the app data is the problem, you could just clear it rather than performing an uninstall. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programatically) should help.